# Windows 10 on iMac mid-2011 High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: bootcamp, imac, disk-utility, windows, efi

Hi guys im trying to install windows 10 on my second internal hard drive ssd with a caddy.
I have already done the usb boot but when i try to boot form the usb to install windows i receive a blue screen and then the imac power off. I tried a lot of things but i think that i have made a little bit of mess,pls im fighting with this imac since 2 days its getting really stressfull.
im posting my screenshots so i hope u colud help me.Thanks a lot[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to boot from the second drive. If this is true, then one possible solution would be to put the Windows boot files in a very small partition on the first drive and there rest of Windows on the second drive. The method of booting is covered in the Microsoft document [BIOS/MBR-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions). Below is an example.

> Since you are EFI booting from the flash drive and installing to BIOS boot, the Graphic User Interface will not allow you to install Windows. Therefore, I have chosen to use the Command Line Interface (CLI).

Below is an example of how to partition the drives. Basically, the difference between your question and below is the following.

- A ~100 MB FAT formatted partition labeled SYSTEM was added to the end of `disk0`.
- `disk0` is hybrid partitioned with partition 4 marked active.
- There are no active partitions marked on `disk1`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Next is a outline of the steps.

1. [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and mount latest Windows ISO from Microsoft. You should do this from macOS or OS X.
2. ExFAT format a flash drive. Use the Master Boot Record (MBR) partitioning scheme.
3. Copy all the files from the Windows ISO to the flash drive.
4. From the [Mac Startup Manager](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202796), EFI boot from the flash drive.
5. Follow the sequence below to open a Command Prompt window.

   When the image below appears, click on `Next`.

   [image]

   When the image below appears, click on `Repair your computer`.

   [image]

   When the image below appears, click on `Troubleshoot`.

   [image]

   When the image below appears, click on `Command Prompt`.

   [image]

   The result should be the image shown below.

   [image]
6. Enter the command `echo list volume | diskpart` to get the drive letter to volume mapping. In my case the following was observed.

   ```
   C: The small volume labeled SYSTEM on disk0
   D: The larger volume labeled BOOTCAMP on disk1
   E: The installation media.
   ```

   If you have different drive letters, then make the appropriate substitutions.
7. Enter the following commands to NTFS format the Windows partitions.

   ```
   format c: /v:SYSTEM /fs:ntfs /q
   format d: /v:BOOTCAMP /fs:ntfs /q
   ```
8. Apply the Windows 10 Pro image to the BOOTCAMP volume. If you need a difference image, then post a comment.

   ```
   dism /apply-image /imagefile:e:\sources\install.wim /name:"Windows 10 Pro" /applydir:d:\ /checkintegrity
   ```
9. Add the boot data and files to the SYSTEM volume and the Master Boot Record (MBR) of `disk0`.

   ```
   bcdboot d:\windows /l en-us /s c: /f bios
   bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
   ```
10. Close the window and turn off the Mac.

    ```
    exit
    ```

    When the image below appears, click on `Turn off your PC`.

    [image]
11. Use the Mac Startup Manager to make Windows the default operating system. Boot to Windows and complete the installation.

    > After you finish installing Windows, do not forget to install the Windows Support Software from Apple.

### References

[BIOS/MBR-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions)
[DISM Image Management Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)
[Dual Boot Win 7 on MBR with Win 10 on GPT](https://superuser.com/questions/1518366/dual-boot-win-7-on-mbr-with-win-10-on-gpt)
[Bootsect Command-Line Options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options)